# How could I get the index of a tuple in haskell?

Tags: haskell

How could I get the index of the highest difference between the elements of a tuple in a list of tuples in haskell?

```
maxDiff :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int
maxDiff [(-5, 3), (-20, 20), (21, 33)] == 2
maxDiff [(-5, 3)] == 1
maxDiff [(-5, 3), (-20, 20), (21, 33), (-50, 30)] == 4
```

Comment: If you want indices, then the results should all be 1 less I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
maxDiff = snd . minimum . (`zip` [1..]) . map (uncurry (-))
```

Comment: @Redu You are right. It assumes that Ord for tuples is implemented lexicographically, and it seems this is implied by the Haskell 2010 Report [11.1 Derived instances of Eq and Ord](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework. ;)

```
import Data.List

tupleDiff :: (Int, Int) -> Int
tupleDiff (x, y) = abs(x - y)

type TupleArray = [(Int, Int)]
maxDiff :: TupleArray -> Maybe Int
maxDiff tuples = elemIndex maxVal tupleDiffs
  where tupleDiffs = map tupleDiff tuples 
        maxVal = maximum tupleDiffs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ maxDiff [(-5, 3), (-20, 20), (21, 33), (-50, 30)]
```